# How can I create multiple different blocks in one module in Drupal 6?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-blocks

I'm using hook_block to create a block with the name of the custom module I'm creating.
I'm not being able to create a block without using myModuleName_block.

Do I need to do different modules for every different block I want to create?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can make several blocks with `hook_block`, just use the `$delta`.

```
function hook_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
  switch ($op) {

    case 'list':
      $blocks[0]['info'] = t('Block 1');
      $blocks[1]['info'] = t('Block 2');
      return $blocks;

    case 'configure':
      if ($delta == 0) {
        // Block 1
      }
      else if ($delta == 1) {
        // Block 1
      }

 ....

}
```

Comment: +1 - just one remark: The $delta doesn't need to be numeric, so if you want to provide a larger number of blocks, it is helpful for maintenance to use a meaningful 'name' instead.

Comment: just a small doubt... if i create multiple blocks like this, how can i invoke a particular block of a module in my page..

Comment: Does this solution require the blocks share the same template?

Comment: @AndrewShooner No, there are some rules for block templates, that makes it possible to share the block template among all blocks that a module has created, but this is a feature, not a requirement.

Comment: Just to clarify, I think the comment `// Block 1` under `$delta == 1` should be "Block 2" instead of "Block 1."